# How to enable push notifications titanium appcelerator 5.5.1.GA

Tags: ios, notifications, titanium, push, appcelerator

I'M trying to enable push notifications appcelerator ios app. I found something about entitlements.plist or appName.entitlements. Which is true ? What must i do for enable push notifications?

Answer (score -1):

You must first look at documentation before asking questions like these. Push is pretty default and well described here:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications

There are also many modules out there for Android, for iOS you don't need modules. You also don't need the server side solution of Appcelerator but you can use pretty much everything you'd like, or write it custom.

Some modules:

- https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.CloudPush
- http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/appcelerator-titanium

More are findable through google ;)

Comment: I looked at this links. I found this. But anyone did not solve my problem. This issue occured after xcode 8 and Titanium 5.5.1.GA. I have not a problem before xcode 8 and 551. If i show you my goole search history, you understand how much search this.

Comment: ah you don't need any module whatsoever for iOS. Just follow the subscribing to push notifications guide. Make sure your certificates are in order